# Add "Now" if something is added to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would not like this code to execute when the cell is empty. This code adds `Now` when I try to delete the contents of the cell.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Range("E" & Target.Row) = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Now
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

More explanation about `Worksheet_Change` can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)

**Edit**:

> I tried test did not work! Date did not show do not know where wrong! –  Horby 6 hours ago

The above code is for one worksheet and should be pasted in the relevant sheet code area. If you want to make it work for all worksheets then use the below code and paste it in the `ThisWorkbook` code area

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Now
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried test did not work! Date did not show do not know where wrong!

Comment: Yes, working now! thank you. if i want code work after line 10?

Comment: what do you mean after line 10?

Comment: Change `If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then` to `If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing And Target.Row > 9 Then`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your code from executing when the Target is empty, just make this small alteration:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Len(Target) Then 
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("E" & Target.Row) = Now()
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should never use `Worksheet_Change` or `Workbook_SheetChange` like that :(

Comment: Would you like to join me for a chat in `XLCODE`?

Comment: thank you for code, i ask also if i want code work after specific line? why you dont like use Worksheet_Change or Workbook_SheetChange ??